# Resources for implementing dependent type theory

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, semantics, dependent-types

I want to implement Martin Löf's intuitionistic type theory in a functional language such as Haskell, preferably also implementing a lexer/parser for the language. How should I start approaching it? Are there any good papers/blog posts/github repo examples that might be useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/) is my go-to for implementing dependent types. It starts from the basics, uses bidirectional types, and has accompanying code in Haskell.

If you're at all interested in type inference, [this paper](https://adam.gundry.co.uk/pub/pattern-unify/) is great, and also has accompanying Haskell code.

David Christiansen has a tutorial on dependent type checking with bidirectional types, with a [Haskell](http://www.davidchristiansen.dk/tutorials/implementing-types-hs.pdf) and [Racket](http://www.davidchristiansen.dk/tutorials/nbe/). More generally, I've heard great things about his book [The Little Typer](https://thelittletyper.com/), though I haven't had a chance to read it myself.

I've heard great things about  [smaltt](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/smalltt)  by András Kovács, particularly for it being an efficient implementation.

Comment: Great answer. Do these tutorials cover bottom, top, unit, etc. types?

Comment: The LambdaPi paper doesn't, but it gives the general pattern for how to add types, so it shouldn't be too hard to add bottom and top.